# Passing a function to React Component and then calling it causes "Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, modal-dialog, react-props

I am trying to display a `Modal` in `React` and once `onClose` is called it should close itself. I have a function called `showModal()`:

```
  showModal = () => {
    this.setState(prev=>({
      modalOpen: !prev.modalOpen
    }));
  };
```

And I am binding it in the constructor:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      ...
      modalOpen: false,
    };
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
  }
```

At some point I am calling my `Modal` component :

```
function = () => {
    ...
    return (
          <div {...attrs}>
            ...
              <div>
                <DocumentModal onClose={this.showModal} show={this.state.modalOpen} document = {documents[0].id} />
                <button onClick={() => {this.showModal()}}>{click me} &raquo;</button>
              </div>
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        );
}
```

And here is the `Modal` component:

```
class DocumentModal extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      id: this.props.document,
    };
  }

  ...

  render() {
    const modalStyles = {
      modal: {
        minWidth: '400px',
        padding: '2rem',
      }
    };

    if (!this.props.show) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <Modal open={this.props.show} little showCloseIcon={true} styles={modalStyles}>
          <div className="item">
            ...
            <button type="button" className="close" aria-label="Close"
                    onClick={() => {this.props.onClose()}}/>
          </div>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Modal.propTypes = {
  onClose: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  show: PropTypes.bool,
  document: PropTypes.string,
};

export default DocumentModal;
```

When clicking on the `close` button inside the `Modal` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: n.props.onClose is not a function
    at n.onClickCloseIcon (modal.js:66)
    at Object.c (react-dom.production.min.js:26)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.production.min.js:25)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.production.min.js:25)
    at p (react-dom.production.min.js:30)
    at b (react-dom.production.min.js:32)
    at y (react-dom.production.min.js:32)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at v (react-dom.production.min.js:31)
    at S (react-dom.production.min.js:34)
```

It might be worth mentioning that there are multiple items for which the `Modal` is rendered. For example 5 different items with 5 different `ID's` but the `onClose` method is still the same for everyone.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add onClose in your Modal component

```
<Modal open={this.props.show} little showCloseIcon={true} styles={modalStyles} onClose={this.props.onModalClose}> //rename your prop function to onModalClose//
```

Comment: It was initally without the `binding` but since I had the same error without the bind I tried adding bind` there.

Comment: Can you try changing this `onClick={() => {this.props.onClose()}}` to `onClick={this.props.onClose}` ? Also can you console.log this.props in render of your modal ? before returning the jsx.

Comment: same result and I get this from console: `[object Object]`

Comment: @kataroty Strange. Can you add all the code of the parent of Modal?

Comment: Well its 800 lines and I dont think I can. Maybe I can add something that would help you help me?

Comment: @kataroty Okay can you do this `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.props.onClose))` where you logged before?

Comment: It prints `undefined`. But I can say that I am passing `boolean` and `string` with props and they are working like they should. So it seems that function is passed incorrectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213154/discussion-between-atin-singh-and-kataroty).